# How to do GridSearchCV choose best_score in skorch

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, pytorch, skorch

I have a trainer class and I define my score  method

```
class Trainer(skorch.NeuralNet):
     """
     Other methods such as train_step_single,validation_step,infer,predict e.tc.
     """
        def score(self, X, Y):
           true_text_list,pred_text_list =[],[]
           for src,tgt in zip(X,Y):
               true_text, pred_text = self.predict(src,tgt)
               true_text_list.append(true_text),pred_text_list.append(pred_text)
           result = bleu.corpus_score(pred_text_list,[true_text_list])
           score = result.score
           print(score)
           return score
```

I  initialized the trainer class with

```
epoch_bleu = EpochScoring(scoring=None, lower_is_better=False)

trainer = Trainer(
            module = Seq2SeqTransformer,
            module__num_encoder_layers = 1,
            module__num_decoder_layers = 1,
            module__emb_size = 8,
            module__nhead = 2,
            module__src_vocab_size = SRC_VOCAB_SIZE,
            module__tgt_vocab_size =TGT_VOCAB_SIZE,
            module__dim_feedforward = 8,
            module__dropout = 0.2,
            criterion = criterion,
            optimizer=torch.optim.Adam,
            lr=0.001,
            batch_size = 5, 
            dataset= translate_dataset,
            optimizer__betas=(0.9, 0.98),
            optimizer__eps=1e-9,
            train_split= split,
            max_epochs=3,
            callbacks=[epoch_bleu],
            device=DEVICE,
           )
```

When I use the fit method

```
trainer.fit(translate_dataset)
gs = GridSearchCV(trainer,params,scoring= None)
gs.fit(train_X ,train_y)
```

My result is

```
 0.026192733573541495
  epoch    score    train_loss    valid_loss     dur
-------  -------  ------------  ------------  ------
      1   0.0262       10.7645       10.7903  1.1093
0.026192733573541495
      2   0.0262       10.7644       10.7906  1.0927
0.026192733573541495
      3   0.0262       10.7645       10.7903  1.0986
0.026192733573541495

print(gs.best_score_, gs.best_params_)
0.010477093429416598 {'lr': 0.003, 'module__dropout': 0.2}
```

This is my  `gs.cv_results_`

```
{'mean_fit_time': array([11.94453502, 13.77196174, 14.05028057, 14.40144386, 14.16046715,
        12.6896481 , 11.84360743, 15.2292047 , 12.22255855]),
 'std_fit_time': array([0.2618251 , 1.07753732, 2.36808454, 1.23219222, 1.86023803,
        1.01203765, 0.28616016, 0.74719985, 0.61968229]),
 'mean_score_time': array([2.27710428, 2.91913524, 2.32345171, 2.53260927, 2.43208547,
        2.31732111, 2.22918859, 2.57366171, 2.31969309]),
 'std_score_time': array([0.1341744 , 0.34804386, 0.1126    , 0.28583804, 0.15907173,
        0.25955979, 0.0675016 , 0.30772863, 0.16703222]),
 'param_lr': masked_array(data=[0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.003, 0.003,
                    0.003],
              mask=[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
                    False],
        fill_value='?',
             dtype=object),
 'param_module__dropout': masked_array(data=[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
              mask=[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
                    False],
        fill_value='?',
             dtype=object),
 'params': [{'lr': 0.001, 'module__dropout': 0.1},
  {'lr': 0.001, 'module__dropout': 0.2},
  {'lr': 0.001, 'module__dropout': 0.3},
  {'lr': 0.002, 'module__dropout': 0.1},
  {'lr': 0.002, 'module__dropout': 0.2},
  {'lr': 0.002, 'module__dropout': 0.3},
  {'lr': 0.003, 'module__dropout': 0.1},
  {'lr': 0.003, 'module__dropout': 0.2},
  {'lr': 0.003, 'module__dropout': 0.3}],
 'split0_test_score': array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]),
 'split1_test_score': array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]),
 'split2_test_score': array([0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.03447158, 0.        ]),
 'split3_test_score': array([0.02619273, 0.        , 0.02619273, 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]),
 'split4_test_score': array([0.02619273, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]),
 'mean_test_score': array([0.01047709, 0.        , 0.00523855, 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.00689432, 0.        ]),
 'std_test_score': array([0.01283177, 0.        , 0.01047709, 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        , 0.        , 0.01378863, 0.        ]),
 'rank_test_score': array([1, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4], dtype=int32)}
```

`best_score_` doesn't use my score method to choose the best score. I am a little confused, about what I am doing wrong.

My questions are

1. What function is GridSearchCV using to select the best score, according to Skorch documentation if I use  `scoring = None`, it uses my  `score()` function defined in the trainer class.
2. Is there a way I can make GridSearchCV use my defined method to choose the best score.

Comment: What shows up in `cv_results_`? Why does your output only appear to show one network fit progress?

Comment: @BenReiniger Thank you for your response. I have added my cv_results to the question, it shows the 46 fits but it majorly contains 0.0 for its score, as I am not using all of my dataset( I am using 100 datapoint at the moment, because of time and speed). I am a little confused as to why I have 46 though I was expecting 9.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with skorch, but it seems like it might be working correctly.  There are 46=9(hyperparameter_points)x5(cv_folds)+1(refit_using_best_params) fits.  If the bleu score is legitimately zero often because of small data, it makes sense to me that the final refit (which I'm assuming is the sole progress report you're showing?) should show a higher score than the cross-validation `best_score_`: it's got a bit more data (although also, is that score reported on a validation set, or...?).

Comment: Thank you very much, following your explanation, it does make sense now. I would try it with all my data points.